# node.js write http response to stream

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, stream, request

i'm fetching some binary data over http. My code looks like:

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
request(url, function(err, res) {
    res.socket.pipe(writeStream);
});
```

now the output file is created but the filesize is 0. The url is correct though, i verified that with wget.

Thanks in advance & best regards

Answer (score 26):

The callback for [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) only supplies one argument, which is a reference to the [response](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_clientresponse) of the request. Try

```
http.request(url, function(res) {
    res.pipe(writeStream);
});
```

Also note that the `ClientResponse` implements [`ReadableStream`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_stream), so you should use `.pipe` rather than `.socket.pipe`.

Comment: `const req = http.request...` and then `req.end()` in order to make it work

Comment: pipe is extremely slow

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming that here `request` is from mikeal's request library rather than being an instance of `http.request`. In that case you can simply do `request(url).pipe(writeStream);`

Remember that for debugging purposes, you can always pipe to `process.stdout`.

Comment: What is the difference if you are using the node core https library, and not the library you mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
request(url, function(err, res) {
  readStream.pipe(res);
  readStream.on('end', function() {
    //res.end({"status":"Completed"});
  });
});
```

Comment: you can only pipe a readable to a writable, not the opposite like you suggest.