# node.js pipe restify http client response

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I have this exact question, except I'm using the restify HttpClient:

[node.js write http response to stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906198/node-js-write-http-response-to-stream)

For clarity, I'm trying to do this:

```
var client = restify.createClient({
    url: "http://www.google.com"
});

client.get("/", function(err,res) {
    res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

It hangs for a few seconds but never writes anything to stdout. Obviously I'm trying to fetch something other than google's homepage, but for example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to user [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) for something like this:

```
var request = require('request'); // npm install request
request('http://www.google.com').pipe(process.stdout);
```

---

Looking at [restify's docs](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#HttpClient) it seems you need to wait for the 'result' event:

```
var client = restify.createClient({
    url: "http://www.google.com"
});

client.get("/", function(err,req) {
  req.on('result',function(err2,res) {
    res.pipe(process.stdout);
    res.on('end',function() {
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: can you reference in the docs where it explains the 'result' event? I didn't see it. But thanks, this works.