# Node writeFile not writing the whole file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to read a csv file and write the contents to a new csv file but am having a few issues in doing so.

My code seems to be reading the file ok and if i log the results of body in the console it shows the complete file. However when I try and write to the file, it does not seem to write all the contents.

The code I am using is as follows...

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var readfile = "http://datafeed.api.productserve.com/datafeed.csv";
var writefile = "app/data/file.csv";

http.get(readfile, function(response) {
    var body = '';
    response.on("data", function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function(){
        fs.writeFile(writefile, body, function(error) {
            if(error) {
                console.error("write error: " + error.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Successful');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Am I doing something incorrect? Or is there some sort of limit on how much you can write?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but you can try this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11906398/5734311

Comment: How big is body, in characters?

Comment: Everything is happening asynchronusly, so go for Promise to finish your work.

Comment: i don't believe the writeFile is the erros cause i tried to readFile and write to local csv file and it worked fine 
try it 
 fs.readFile(readfile,'utf8', function(err, response) {
    console.log("response",response)

        fs.writeFile(writefile, response, function(error) {
            if(error) {
                console.error("write error: " + error.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Successful');
            }
        });
});