# Filename is written, but its file size is zero bytes

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to check whether a file exists on the server. If it doesn't, Node needs to download a file from the specified URL. The following does download the filename, but the filesize is zero (so it doesn't download it properly). What am I doing wrong?

The code to download the file is in the catch block. Thanks.

```
getApiDetails.then(
    apiData => {
        let imagesFolder = 'public/city_images/';
        // Only do the following if the city was found by the pixarbay api. If a city wasn't found, we assign it to default.jpg
        if (apiData.largeImageURL !== 'default.jpg') {

            const imageFileExtension = apiData.largeImageURL.substring(apiData.largeImageURL.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
            const imageFile = apiData.city+'.'+imageFileExtension;

            // Check whether file exists, if not, download it
            try {
                if(fs.statSync(__dirname+'/'+imagesFolder+imageFile).isFile()){
                    // Rename the path so it can be accessed like a local file and not always fetched from 3rd party api server (hotlinking is a no no)
                    apiData.largeImageURL = imagesFolder+imageFile;
                    resolve(apiData);
                }
            }
            catch(e) {
                // apiData.largeImageURL is an online jpeg file 
                let file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+'/'+imagesFolder+imageFile); // The path to the file the stream is writing to 
                https.get(apiData.largeImageURL, function(response) {
                    response.pipe(file);
                });
                // Rename the path so it can be accessed like a local file and not always fetched from 3rd party api server (hotlinking is a no no)
                apiData.largeImageURL = imagesFolder+imageFile;
                resolve(apiData);
            }

            ...
```

Comment: You might try piping to `process.stdout` for debugging purposes. Are you absolutely certain that the `get` is actually succeeding? See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906198/node-js-write-http-response-to-stream) question.

Comment: I can't pipe to process.stdout from my web host, which is where I'm running this from. I then realised I should try it locally. It worked locally (well, the browser hung, but the file downloaded correctly). Locally, doing response.pipe(process.stdout) filled my console with a stream of binary, but perhaps I'm not doing it correctly.