# How can I access image files in MongoDB and send them to the client using Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, binaryfiles

I stored some image files in MongoDB using mongoose. The images are submitted from an HTML form, and then sent to MongoDB through an Express POST request.  Then, I want to access those image files in MongoDB through a GET request and then send them to the client side. The code for this looks like this:

```
app.get("/showallimages", (req, res) => {

    Image.find({}).exec((error, records) => { // Image is the database schema model. 

        var img1 = Buffer.from(records[0].img.data, "base64"); // First image coming from MongoDB.
        var img2 = Buffer.from(records[1].img.data, "base64"); // Second image coming from MongoDB.
        var images = [img1, img2];

        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "image/png",
        })

        var i = 0;
        for (i; i <= images.length; i++) {
            res.end(images[i]); // I am expecting this to send both images to the client side, but instead I am only getting the first image to be displayed. 
        }

    })

})
```

If I console.log “images”, I get the binary data of both files:

```
console.log(images); 

  <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 00 00 64 00 64 00 00 ff ec 00 11 44 75 63 
6b 79 00 01 00 04 00 00 00 22 00 00 ff ee 00 0e 41 64 6f 62 65 00 64 ... 8728 more bytes>,
  <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 05 39 00 00 03 84 08 06 00 
00 00 6a f3 35 f1 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 00 f2 ... 397757 more bytes>
```

I am expecting this to send both images to the client side, but instead I am only getting the first image to be displayed.

Any explanation as to how I can send more than one file in this process is appreciated. Also let me know if I am choosing the right way to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: you have 2 files that you need to iterate over ( stream both the http.resp ) by  1 . open a writestream 2. pipe the w-strream to the http response 3. iterate files 3.a. open readstream on input file, pipe r-stream to w-stream  at end close the http response   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906198/node-js-write-http-response-to-stream

Comment: Even if you change to `res.send` I don't believe you can send multiple files down in a single response. you would need to combine them into zip or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code have an logic error. when res.end() is called, express ends the response process in the first image, your loop does not reach the next iteration.
Also you cannot have multiple responses for one request. But you can send the Buffer array with JSON representation using `res.json(images)`.

**In the client**, to display the images received as buffers from the server: you need to convert them to the original format doing this:

```
// server response
const images = response.map(buffer => {
  const rawBuffer = buffer.toString("base64");
  const imageSrc = "data:image/png;base64," + rawBuffer;
  const image = document.createElemment("img");
  image.src = imageSrc;
  return image;
})

/* 
In this method you can control how you will show the images in the client 
(to test, just append to any div)
*/
```

Or, if you just want to display the images without any manipulation try this:

```
app.get("/showallimages", (req, res) => {

    Image.find({}).exec((error, records) => { // Image is the database schema model. 

        var img1 = Buffer.from(records[0].img.data, "base64"); // First image coming from MongoDB.
        var img2 = Buffer.from(records[1].img.data, "base64"); // Second image coming from MongoDB.
        var images = [img1, img2];

        const formatedImages = images.map(buffer => {
          return `<img src="data:image/png;base64,${buffer.toString("base64")}"/>`
        }).join("")
        
        res.send(formatedImages)

    })

})
```

Comment: I tried both `res.send (images)`  and `res.json(images)` inside and outside the loop, and I am getting this error:

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: remove `res.writeHead()` call, res.send() and res.json() automatically sets the content-type header.

Comment: my purpose is to display the two images on the client side. I did what you suggested and tried  `res.send (images)` which, on the client side, downloads one of the images. I then tried `res.json(images)` which displays the binary data on the browser.

Comment: I have edited the answer, test if this new approach works.