# Sending webm blob to nodejs and saving it on the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm having troubles saving an incoming webm blob to the server. I'm using react-video-recorder on NextJS like this:

```
<VideoRecorder
              onRecordingComplete={(videoBlob) => {
                // Do something with the video...
                fetch("/api/video", 
                  method: "post",
                  body: videoBlob,
                })
                  .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("done");
                    return response;
                  })
                  .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('error', err);
                  });
                console.log(url); 
// output: blob:http://localhost:3000/99a5b711-f3d5-481d-9e04-8981d1be3727 
 
                console.log(videoBlob); 
// output Blob {size: 307028, type: "video/webm;codecs="vp8,opus""}

              }}
            />
```

On the api side I'm trying to save the file like this. It does save something, but is only the first chunk or buffer. How can I capture and write the file to my server?

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  fs.writeFile('test.webm', req.body, function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log('video saved');
    } );
}
```

Comment: example of http.response - which is a stream - being piped on node server side should offer a solution to you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906198/node-js-write-http-response-to-stream

Answer (score 0):

I did that task by doing this.
I saved the recordingChunks/Video blob to a state and then sent it to the Nodejs server from Reactjs Frontend

FrontEnd code:-

```
const blob = new Blob(context.data.recordedChunks, {
    type: "video/webm",
});
const fd = new FormData()
fd.append('video', blob)
axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/video/blob_video`, fd)
    .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Backend code:-

```
router.post('/blob_video', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (req.files.video !== undefined) {
            const video = req.files.video // this is your file do what ever you want with it
            const videoname = Date.now() + req.files.video.name + ".webm"
            video.mv(`${__dirname}/../your_path/${videoname}`, err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    return res.json({ err })
                }
            })
        }


        res.json(req.body)
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({ success: false, err: err, msg: "Server error" })
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

Using express-fileupload to upload a file you can do it with your favourite one.